# Why doesn't echo php in css.php not work?

Tags: php, css, echo

I've created a CSS file with a PHP-extention, called all.php. This file looks like:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/css; charset=utf-8");

session_start();

$color = $_SESSION['color']; ?>

.className {
   background-color: <? echo $color; ?>;
}
```

This file's called on every page using

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/all.php" media="screen">
```

When I echo the `$_SESSION` as plain text on a php file, everything works just fine. So, the SESSION is set properly, somehow it doens't work in the css.php file. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you paste the contents of the `all.php` file when viewed in your browser?

Comment: without knowing what the other files look like, make sure that the session array is assigned a color/value and that you're using the correct case for the session class and that you started the session inside all files using sessions; this is just a guess but fairly confident about it. See if error reporting shows anything and check if the session is indeed set and not empty everywhere.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Using `<link rel="stylesheet="...` with an external CSS file is best practice for organization compared to inline `<style>`.

Comment: @Fred-ii- He's using an externally generated stylesheet using php for dynamic serving. That is not an appropriate answer to this question.

Comment: @JonUleis okilee dokilee. well, OP's not responding, you're the only one chatting back to me.

Comment: @mopsyd and my comment to the other guy applies to you too; I'm out of this question now. You guys take over, seems like they're only responding to answers.

Comment: I tested your code on my PC, using `<?php` instead of `<?` and it works. So use `<?php`. Also, you should use session_start as first line of your script.

Comment: In addition to @AnthonyB's comment, `<?= 'foo' ?>` is shorthand for `<?php echo 'foo' ?>` and is not tied to the status of the `shorttag_open` setting.

Comment: if you `echo $_SESSION['color'];` in your other php files, what is the output? and also, why do you assign `$_SESSION['color']` value to `$color` and then use it in your `css`? why don't you use `$_SESSION['color']` directly in your `css` like this `background-color: <? echo $_SESSION['color']; ?>;`?

Comment: @EhsanT Unfortunately css won't let me echo any php directly into the stylesheet, only on the .php page itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. In the original document I started the page with the header, then session_start(). Those should be switched. The page has to start with session_start(), otherwise it will be treated as CSS.

Comment: Just FYI: in the future try using `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors','1');` at the top of your PHP scripts so that your script shows all errors and warnings. Usually PHP shows warnings if the header call goes before `session_start`. And by default on some installations, warnings don't show up.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have short tags turned off in your php.ini (which you should do).

Instead of `<? echo $color; ?>;`

Use `<?php echo $color; ?>;`

or `<?= $color; ?>;`

Comment: replace `$color` with `(isset($color) && !is_null($color) ? $color : 'magenta')`. If you get magenta, you didn't have a color set in your $_SESSION variable.

Comment: I tested on my PC, indeed with short tags it does not work, with `<?php` it works.

Answer (score -1):

Inside the css.php the file itself doesnt know about the $_SESSION variable you have set in your files where you're including the css.php file, because it doesnt know which Session you use.

`echo session_id();` outside css.php to get your Session Id. I mean where you get values back from your Session variables like you mentioned.

Then set `session_id() = (the id here)` inside your css.php

Comment: `$_SESSION` persists based on the cookie. Your method will break as soon as the session id changes, which is any time the session cookie is re-issued. Cookies are sent to the server with all requests, so the stylesheet would have access to the same session as the page.